# How to convert X days to seconds and vice-versa in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am storing some time related fields in my database. When the field gets stored, it takes the value like "**50 days**" to make the UX better, then on the backend I convert this number to seconds with `strtotime('50 days', 0);` which results in *4320000*.

The question is, how do I make this number of seconds go back to **50** (or something lower if time has passed) to represent the remaining *day(s)* (ie. it returns an integer)?

Comment: The linked to question demonstrates how to do this although you may  need to alter some of the examples if it is more than 6 days.

Comment: @JohnConde Well, how? I guess that the linked answer doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: That's gonna depend on the answer you choose to implement. The ones with DateTime are the easiest as date_diff() will produce a DateInterval object that easily exports the differences as number of days.

Comment: I don't know why you just cant divide the number of seconds you stored by 86400 to get days. Maybe I'm not reading the question correctly.